# How to I log into the Redmine webapp from the Bitnami virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, redmine, bitnami

I want to try out Redmine, fortunately I've found the Bitnami redmine virtual machine which I have now downloaded.
I have started the services as per the instructions in [how to start and stop servers](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_Redmine).

So I can see that the services are up and running, but now what? How do i get to the web-page. I cannot see any web browser in the VM all I get is the console/command line.

Now that the services are running how do i launch the web application?
How do I launch the web-browser so that I can see the default redmine webpage.

Normally I would launch fireforx/chrome and go to the localhost address, however with the bitnami virtual machine I've downloaded I only have the command line.

Comment: There is a quick-start guide on how to access virtual appliances here: https://wiki.bitnami.com/Virtual_Appliances_Quick_Start_Guide#How_to_access_the_Bitnami_Virtual_Appliance.3f

Comment: Thanks, I have already manually configured the IP address of the VM. I only want to launch the browser from inside the VM and browse to the ip address and port, i.e I know the IP address and port are 192.168.10.11:8080, now how do I browse to this ip address and port. Where is the web-browser. I can only see a command line prompt

Comment: You should be able to access to that IP via the browser in your host operating system as if you were accessing that IP in your local network, you don't need to have any browser inside your VM.

Comment: aha, I see, I had assumed that with no external application(host) or anything I could use the VM and only the VM to try out the Redmine instance didn't realize that I would need the host to access it. Thank you though